# Google font turns (c) into ©

Tags: user-interface, fonts, google-font-api

I'm using the following google font in my react app:
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Manrope?preview.text=(c)&preview.text_type=custom
and, as in title, the browser (or the font itself?), turns all occurrences of (c) into the copyright character. It happens in both static texts and inputs. You can easily replicate this by just visiting the link and typing something in the input.

I know nothing about this so not sure if this is the right place to ask such question but maybe some of you had a similar problem? Is it a property of this font and nothing can be done about this or there's something I could do to change this behavior?

Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved by adding this to my css:

```
* {
    font-variant-ligatures: none;
}
```